# Reevoo API filtering

Tags: python-2.7, filtering

I am using Python to query the Reevoo API. As far as I can tell, the options for filtering are somewhat limited and the docs are an exhaustive list of what query parameters you can use. I was wondering if anybody had found a way to filter customer experience reviews with a date range?

Currently my <strike>hack</strike> solution is to use a generator which calls the API page by page and yields the review if its `publish_date` is after a certain date, which is obviously really inefficient. It doesn't help that the API returns the results slightly out of order, so I can't break/return as soon as I find one review that's out of range.

```
for i in range(number_of_pages, 0, -1):
    # API call wrapper
    page_of_reviews = self.reevoo.get_customer_experience_review_list(self.trkref, older_reviews=True,
                                                                                  page=i, per_page=30)
    page_of_reviews = json.loads(page_of_reviews.text.replace('\r\n', ''))
    customer_experience_reviews = page_of_reviews.get('customer_experience_reviews')
    processed_reviews = self.process_customer_experience_reviews(customer_experience_reviews)

    for item in processed_reviews['review_list']:
        if from_dt:
            if datetime.strptime(item['publish_date'], '%Y-%m-%d') >= datetime.strptime(from_dt, '%Y-%m-%d'):
                yield item
        else:
            yield item
```

I've scoured the [docs](http://reevoo.github.io/docs/reevooapi/customer-experience-review/customer-experience-review-list/) and Reevoo's GitHub page and haven't found anything, but in the hopes that some random person on the Internet has found a workaround... Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I emailed Reevoo to ask about date filtering and the short answer is that there is no way to filter or sort by date.**

Explanation from the email:

> Unfortunately, we cannot filter reviews by date as when we display the reviews, they are not necessarily in date order. For example, reviews with written content come before those which don't have written content as they have more value to the consumer. We would also prefer that you refreshed everything at least once a day, because older reviews sometimes have to be renewed or customers may sometimes request that there reviews be amended.
>
> I understand why you would lie to do date filtering but at the moment, if you are caching reviews on your server, this is the way we prefer you to do it.